# NGINX Config Part of WordPress site shall be accessible only via separate domain name

Tags: nginx, configuration, wordpress

I have one WordPress installation on an Ubuntu 20.04 NGINX server. Most of the WordPress pages shall be accessed via the main domain example.com, but one section shall only be accessible over the second domain example.net. How shall I modify my current NGINX config below to make that happen? I shall only have one WordPress installation in one directory (except for test.example.com).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    # www to non-www for SEO canonical reasons
    return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    # PHP
    location ~ \.php$ {
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off; access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
    }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
    }

    # (For WordPress permalinks)
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com/test;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    # PHP
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off; access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
    }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
    }

    # (For WordPress permalinks)
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

Comment: WordPress will not like this. It is not something you should really attempt.

Answer (score 0):

A new server block is the solution:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.net;
    root /var/www/example/othersection;
}
```